# Paypal Buy Now Button with Dynamic Dropdown Values

Tags: javascript, php, html, paypal

I am trying to use the PayPal 'Buy Now' customized button with a dropdown above it in an PHP application.
Following is the snapshot as how I created it on their site:

[image: Buy Now Button Creation]

Using that I got the following HTML code:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="JZ8L4BBU6CEQA">
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
    <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Packages">Packages
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <select name="os0">
<option value="Option 1">Option 1 $1.00 USD</option>
<option value="Option 2">Option 2 $2.00 USD</option>
   </select> 
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Now the problem that I am facing is that I want to populate values in this dropdown from my database. It is not always possible to login to the PayPal site and then make changes to the button code and then use the updated button code.

Please help me in populating dynamic values to this dropdown from some database table and in order to achieve this what setting should I use while creating the PayPal button. Please help and thanks in advance to this wonderful community.

Comment: you can use paypal button manager API for that. check out https://github.com/paypal/buttonmanager-sdk-php

Comment: you can go for clear text button and then use your own logic to populate the dropdown values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found answer to my own question after a detailed research. The good thing is that yes we can add dynamic values to this dropdown. These values can be fetched up from our database and the passed on to this PayPal dropdown.

For that you have to make some different configurations while creating the PayPal button.
Here are its steps:

- From your PayPal account click on the 'Create New Button' link (Highlighted in Red box)

[image]

- The PayPal button creation wizard has 3 steps. In the first step select configurations as per you needs with the dropdown added to the PayPal button.
  [image]

  In step 2 of the wizard uncheck 'Save Button At PayPal' checkbox as follows.

  [image]

  No special configuration required in step 3. Do it as per your needs.
- After completing the wizard, you are provided with the HTML code of the PayPal button as follows. Click on the 'Remove code protection' link as below (Highlighted in red box)
  [image]

  As a result you will get a code that is somewhat changed and has additional parameters with it. These parameters can be used to pass our dynamic values. You will get code as below:

  ```
  <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
  <!-- List of many other required input hidden parameters here. 
       Required, but not relevant to this answer. 
  -->
  <table>
  <tr>
   <td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Packages">Packages</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <select name="os0">
      <option value="Option 1">Option 1 $0.01 USD</option>
      <option value="Option 2">Option 2 $0.02 USD</option>
     </select> 
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
  <input type="hidden" name="option_select0" value="Option 1">
  <input type="hidden" name="option_amount0" value="0.01">
  <input type="hidden" name="option_select1" value="Option 2">
  <input type="hidden" name="option_amount1" value="0.02">
  <input type="hidden" name="option_index" value="0">
  <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
  ```
- Now in order to add dynamic values to this dropdown above the PayPal button, just query the values from the required database table and then with help of a for loop, create the dropdown option values and its equivalent input hidden tags on the fly. 
  So suppose my database table had 4 rows then my code will evaluate as

  ```
  <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
  <!-- List of many other required input hidden parameters here. 
           Required, but not relevant to this answer. 
  -->
  <table>
  <tr>
   <td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Packages">Packages</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <select name="os0">
      <option value="Option 1">Option 1 $0.01 USD</option>
      <option value="Option 2">Option 2 $0.02 USD</option>
      <option value="Option 3">Option 3 $0.03 USD</option>
      <option value="Option 4">Option 4 $0.04 USD</option>
    </select> 
   </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
  <input type="hidden" name="option_select0" value="Option 1">
  <input type="hidden" name="option_amount0" value="0.01">

  <input type="hidden" name="option_select1" value="Option 2">
  <input type="hidden" name="option_amount1" value="0.02">

  <input type="hidden" name="option_select2" value="Option 3">
  <input type="hidden" name="option_amount2" value="0.03">

  <input type="hidden" name="option_select3" value="Option 3">
  <input type="hidden" name="option_amount3" value="0.04">

  <input type="hidden" name="option_index" value="0">
  <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
  <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
  </form>
  ```
- Note that above is the direct code, use a for loop to dynamically create these elements. So finally for a single dropdown option, you need to create a option tag element and its equivalent two input hidden elements as follows:

  ```
  <option value="Option 3">Option 3 $0.03 USD</option>
  <input type="hidden" name="option_select2" value="Option 3">
  <input type="hidden" name="option_amount2" value="0.03">
  ```
- These hidden parameters are passed to PayPal once with click the 'Buy Now'/'Pay Now' button and the right amount is billed to the buyer as per the selected option in the dropdown above the button.

Comment: If you dont sign in and create the button then you get options in full in the html and you are not forced even then to use any drop down and can manipulate the html for the hidden amount input field. This would not be recommended as a payment method that automatically sends the product as the amount can be altered by the client but I can see scenarios where that would not be critical.